# Load json from file with swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to load a json string from a file with this code.

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
        print(contents)
    } catch {
        // contents could not be loaded
        print("could not be loaded")
    }

} else {

}
```

But I get the "could not be loaded" message. Is the code wrong? or shall I put the file in a specific folder? At the moment I am putting it a a folder called models.

**EDIT:** I checked the error content and there is no problem with the location of the json file, the problemoccure when I try to convert it to a String. It tells me that the encoding is different ...

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=264 "Die Datei „data.json“ konnte
>   nicht geöffnet werden, da die Textcodierung des Inhalts nicht bestimmt
>   werden kann."

Comment: Put that file in your target's root directory

Comment: Print the error: `/*...*/ catch(error) { print(error)` – what does it say?

Comment: Check the target membership of your json file.

Comment: Can you post the json content please? It seems like there is an issue with the format of your file. Maybe use this to verify if your json is valid: https://jsonlint.com/ Or do you have a link to a repo on github or alike?

Comment: The JSON is valid, I cheked it

Comment: Read the file as Data (not a String) and check if that works. JSON decoding should be done from data anyway.

Comment: Please translate the error message to English. Thanks.

Comment: @rmaddy "file could not be opened, because it's encoding could not be determined". Looks like the file is present in the bundle but not readable/no text.

Answer (score 5):

First make sure that you have marked the `copy item if needed` checkmark, and your target is marked also while you add your .json file, after that your main issue is your way to load your file, you need to do this with `Data` instead of `String`

**Use this method to load your json and get the results in a callback**

```
     func loadJSON(finishedClosure:@escaping ((_ jsonObject:[String:AnyObject]?,_ error: NSError?) ->Void))
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourJSON", ofType: "json") else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                finishedClosure(nil, NSError(domain: "JSON file don't founded", code: 998, userInfo: nil)) 
            }
            return
        }
        //Load file data part
        guard let jsonData = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))) else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                finishedClosure(nil, NSError(domain: "can convert to data", code: 999, userInfo: nil))  
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    finishedClosure(jsonObject,nil)
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                finishedClosure(nil,error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both the posted screenshot and the code are not related to the question and do not help to solve the OP's problem. If you don't agree, explain *why* they help.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I think the user is getting a problem loading a json from file, so I add a nice implementation and add an screenshot to make it sure that he add the file correctly in their own project, can you explain why did you think this don't help? if you read my method implementation do what you suggest in your comment load the json content and read the file as data

Comment: 1. The screenshot highlights the wrong checkbox (if you are concerned that the file if properly copied to the bundle).

Comment: 2. A better hint would be to check the build phases if the file is in the proper copy phase.

Comment: 3. The code is unrelated because it does not solve the problem (file loading). Instead it shows how to decode JSON on a background thread.

Comment: 4. The code is broken. It does not compile and contains other errors.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the code also includes the file loading problem, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe you are right about the image i will remove it

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe thanks for your feedbacks anyway, you make me improve today, by the way the OP question title is `Load json from file with swift 3`

Comment: @ReinierMelian : Your disclaimer **First make sure that you have marked the copy item if needed checkmark, and your target is marked also while you add your .json file,** helped!!! I was wondering why the file was not being read in the code.. Thanks man!

Comment: @Vineet your welcome dude!, I am glad to help, best regards and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 - parse JSON file as String and Data type**

The error indicates that the file couldn't be read as string because the text encoding couldn't be determined. You should explicitly provide the actual encoding of the json file.

To check the encoding of your file, open the file in XCode and have a look at file inspector at the right side bar:

[image: Encoding of the file]

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json"),
   let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
  do {

    // here you have your json parsed as string:
    let jsonString = try? String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    // but it is better to use the type data instead:
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
  }
  catch {
    //Handle error
  }
}
```